# Richardson-Lucy for bitmap image

Tags: image-processing

I am new to Python and am trying to modify an existing Richardson-Lucy program for an image that I have.
Specifically, I have a bitmap image 'flower2.bmp' that I am using to test the following program:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2
from skimage import color, data, restoration


Image.open('flower2.bmp').convert('L').save('flower2_gray.bmp')

astro = Image.open('flower2_gray.bmp')

psf = np.ones((5, 5)) / 25

astro = conv2(astro, psf, 'same')
# Add Noise to Image
astro_noisy = astro.copy()
astro_noisy += (np.random.poisson(lam=25, size=astro.shape) - 10) / 255.

# Restore Image using Richardson-Lucy algorithm
deconvolved_RL = restoration.richardson_lucy(astro_noisy, psf, iterations=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(8, 5))
plt.gray()

for a in (ax[0], ax[1], ax[2]):
       a.axis('off')

ax[0].imshow(astro)
ax[0].set_title('Original Data')

ax[1].imshow(astro_noisy)
ax[1].set_title('Noisy data')

ax[2].imshow(deconvolved_RL, vmin=astro_noisy.min(), vmax=astro_noisy.max())
ax[2].set_title('Restoration using\nRichardson-Lucy')


fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.02, hspace=0.2,
                    top=0.9, bottom=0.05, left=0, right=1)

plt.show()
```

Below is the image output. I would appreciate help understanding why the Restoration image is black.

[image: 1]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [restoration.richardson_lucy documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.restoration.html#skimage.restoration.richardson_lucy) notes that the function has an optional "clip" argument, which is true by default:

> **clip** : boolean, optional
> True by default. If true, pixel value of the result above 1 or under -1 are thresholded for skimage pipeline compatibility.

However, the `astro` image read from `Image.open` has nominal range [0, 255]. I'm guessing that all pixels in astro are >= 1, so that the result after clipping to [-1, 1] is simply a constant image of ones. This could explain the plot.

The fix is to divide `astro_noisy` by 255 before passing it to restoration.richardson_lucy.

Comment: Thank you for your message.  Dividing astro_noisy by 255 fixed the problem.  However, could you please explain a bit more why that is needed?  In the line 'astro_noisy += (np.random.poisson(lam=25, size=astro.shape) - 10) / 255' I already divided astro_noisy by 255.

Comment: That line is an addition assignment, `+=`. It divides the added noise by 255, but not the image itself, which came from `astro_noisy = astro.copy()`.